# Converting list of lists to numpy array gives different results

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I receive arrays of 9 doubles via tcp, split them, convert with np.array() method, store them in list, and finally again convert this list to numpy array, so i could save it, and later load to train keras model.

Each time I re-run code, shape of output is (500, 6) or (500,) randomly,
I don't change anything, just keep running same code and I get different results.

1. How is that possible?
2. How to convert (n,) to (n, 6)? I Tried with .reshape()

Edit: my full code:

```
def tcp_server_get_training_data():
host = "localhost"
port = 5367
msg = ""
mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mySocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
mySocket.bind((host, port))
# print(socket.getfqdn())
# print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn()))
mySocket.listen(1)
print('waiting for connection...')
conn, addr = mySocket.accept()
print("Connection from: " + str(addr))
x = []
y = []
i = 0
n = 500
while i < n:
    data = conn.recv(128)
    doubles_sequence = array.array('d', data)
    doubles_sequence2 = np.array(doubles_sequence)
    x.append(doubles_sequence2[:6])
    y.append(doubles_sequence2[-3:])
    i += 1
    print(str(round((i/n)*100, 2))+"%")
    #print(doubles_sequence[:6])
xp = np.array(x)
yp = np.array(y)
print("X shape: "+str(xp.shape))
print("y shape: "+str(yp.shape))
np.save(file='x', arr=xp)
np.save(file='y', arr=yp)
conn.close()
```

when I print x with shape (500,6) i get:

```
>>> x.shape
(500, 6)
>>> x
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. , -0.29219246,  0. , 0. ],
      [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.34277358,  0. , 0. ],
      [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.34277358,  0. , 0. ],
```

when I print x with shape (500,) i get:

```
>>> x.shape
(500,)
>>> x
array([array([ 0.,  0. ,  0. , -0.29219246,  0., 0.  ]),
       array([ 0. , 0.  , 0. , 0.34277358, 0., 0.]),
       array([ 0. ,  0.,  0., -0.10241638,  , dtype=object)
```

I'd really appreciate some help, I tried to figure it out on my own, but after few hours just get frustrated.
 I'm relatively new in programming and spend more time on C#, in python I'm very confused without type declaration.

Comment: There's something missing from this code to explain the difference I think. Please given a [mcve]. None of those printed outputs come from the actual `print` functions in your code, they come from the REPL/Interactive Console

Comment: Can you post a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: this is all of code. I run this and from print functions in code get (500,) sometimes, and sometimes (500,6) for x and (500,3) for y, as it is desired to be.

Comment: The first array is a 2d numeric dtype array, the second 1d object dtype containing arrays.  Most commonly that's result of trying to make an array from arrays that vary in shape.  Most of those 500 might be (6,) but one or more may be smaller or larger.  When creating an array from external sources it can be hard to keep shapes consistent.

Comment: Just a quick guess, `doubles_sequence2[:6]` makes sure that this array isn't longer than 6, but it may be shorter.  I'd suggest a more robust size check at this point.

Comment: Yeah, there was something wrong with size of received data, I changed buffer size in conn.recv(128) to 72 to get just 9 doubles and it works now. Thanks a lot!